# Rails for Zombies Lab 4 > Exercise 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-for-zombies

I stucked in the fourth Rails for Zombies lab at the third exercise. This is my task: *Create action that will create a new Zombie and then redirect to the created zombie's show page*.
I've got the following params array:

```
params = { :zombie => { :name => "Greg", :graveyard => "TBA" } }
```

I wrote the following code as a solution:

```
def create
   @zombie = Zombie.create   
   @zombie.name = params[ :zombie [ :name ] ]   
   @zombie.graveyard = params[ :zombie [ :graveyard ] ]
   @zombie.save   

   redirect_to(create_zombie_path)
end
```

But when I submit it I got the following error:
`#<TypeError: can't convert Symbol into Integer>`

I know that I made a mistake but I cannot figure out where. Please help me.

Comment: `zombies` isn't a useful tag, as it doesn't make sense by itself. I've changed it to `rails-for-zombies`.

Comment: @skaffman if you don't like the `rails-for-zombies` tag, please explain what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
def create
   @zombie = Zombie.create(params[:zombie])
   redirect_to @zombie
end
```

Comment: You can also just do `redirect_to Zombie.create(params[:zombie])`

Comment: How can we do this using Rails 4 Strong params?

Comment: @Freedom_Ben - See Anurag Aryan answer below

Answer (score 4):

First of all you are doing a mistake here

```
@zombie.name = params[ :zombie [ :name ] ]
```

it should be

```
   @zombie.name = params[:zombie][:name]
```

You can try doing this

```
def create
   @zombie = Zombie.create(params[:zombie])
   redirect_to(create_zombie_path)
end
```

This makes your code **DRY**, as per wiki

> "Don't repeat yourself"(DRY) means that
>   information is located in a single,
>   unambiguous place. For example, using
>   the ActiveRecord module of Rails, the
>   developer does not need to specify
>   database column names in class
>   definitions. Instead, Ruby on Rails
>   can retrieve this information from the
>   database based on the class name.

Comment: You have a typo at @zombie.name = params[:zombie][:name ]]

Answer (score 3):

I am not able to make out any error in your code(except the `[`, `]` things but I think it came while pasting the code here, as it is uniform throughout and when I tried it, I got another error `NoMethodError: undefined method '[]' for :zombie:Symbol`), but it can be definitely refractored like this:

```
def create
   @zombie = Zombie.new(params[:zombie])
   if @zombie.save
     redirect_to @zombie
   else
     render :action => :new
   end
end
```

Check whether the `params` hash from the controller is exactly the same by using `p params`.

Answer (score 1):

```
def create
   @zombie = Zombie.create(params.require(:zombie).permit(:name, :graveyard))
   redirect_to zombie_path(@zombie)
end
```

That's what worked for me.

Comment: Nice, thanks.  For others, note that this is the new way of doing it using Strong Parameters for Rails 4.  The other answers aren't wrong, but they are outdated (and potentially unsafe)

Answer (score 1):

this works for me

```
def create
       @zombie = Zombie.create(zombie_params)
       redirect_to zombie_path(@zombie)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

def create
  @zombie = Zombie.create(params[:zombie])
  redirect_to(@zombie)
end

is the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

```
def create
  @zombie = Zombie.create(params[:zombie])
  redirect_to(@zombie)
end
```

is the correct answer

(sorry for the double post, didnt notice the code box the first time)

Answer (score 0):

```
def create
     @zombie = Zombie.create(params[:zombie])
     redirect_to (zombies_path)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

## Original Hint #1

> You'll want to pass params[:zombie] to the Zombie.create method.

## Original Hint #2

> Then use the redirect_to method with the new zombie to send them to
>   the right zombie_path

## Original Hint #3

A possible correct answer is:

```
def create
  @zombie = Zombie.create(params[:zombie])
  redirect_to zombie_path(@zombie)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the zombie_params function is already defined, you can just use it as a parameter to the create function.

```
class ZombiesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @zombie= Zombie.create(zombie_params)
    redirect_to @zombie
  end

  private

  def zombie_params
    params.require(:zombie).permit(:name, :graveyard)
  end
end
```