# Rails for Zombies Level 4 Exercise 3 (WITH Rails 4 Strong Parameters)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters, rails-for-zombies

I am doing the above exercise on railsforzombies.org, and I simply cannot figure out why it keeps telling me I am not using strong parameters. I am using the examples shown in the video as a guide, but I keep getting the message:

"Did not create a new Zombie using Rails 4 Strong Parameters."

Here is my code:

```
class ZombiesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @zombie = Zombie.create(params[:zombie])
    redirect_to @zombie
  end

  private

  def zombie_params
    params.require(:zombie).permit([:name, :graveyard])
  end
end
```

Here is the example which I am basing my solution off of:
(I can't post pictures yet)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jyw8n.jpg

I have read the solution listed at [Rails for Zombies Lab 4 > Exercise 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219691/rails-for-zombies-lab-4-exercise-3)
However, this example does not solve the 'Strong Parameters' error. I also cannot comment on that topic, so I have started a new one for Rails 4.

Comment: I had previously tried `redirect_to zombie_path` but in trying to use the solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219691/rails-for-zombies-lab-4-exercise-3 I changed it to @zombie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the method `zombie_params` filters the parameters correctly.

But you're not using that method when you create the `Zombie` object.

Instead of doing

```
@zombie = Zombie.create(params[:zombie])
```

use the method

```
@zombie = Zombie.create(zombie_params)
```

Comment: Thank you; I had tried that, thinking it made more sense, but it was before I had switched `redirect_to zombie_path` to `redirect_to @zombie`. Much appreciated; somebody vote him up for me. :)